# jQuery customizable Bar graphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, bar-chart

I am trying to use `jquery bargraphs` in my website. I need a suggestion that I can easily customize the bar graphs. Also, I `need to download the bar graph into excel sheet with graph image`. Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://www.highcharts.com/ you can customize the bar graphs easily here. Also you can download the graphs in csv format.